# How to change the psql version used by default?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have installed two versions of PostgreSQL: 9.6.5 and 10.6. 
Now when I run 'psql --version', I see that it is 10.6 used by default.

I need to set 9.6.5 version as default, because there is system reqierements of app from my job.

OS Ubuntu 18.04.

Sorry for my English

Comment: Change your `PATH` to point to the new binaries

Comment: as @a_horse_with_no_name already mentioned you need to change the `PATH` to point to the binary of postgresql.9.6.5. What os are you using?

Comment: @iLuvLogix I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Do you know how to add/change a path on Ubuntu or do you need help with that?

Comment: @iLuvLogix unfortunately not. 
I know how to add path variables to /etc/environments (it's simple).
But there is no psql's paths in /etc/environments.

Comment: I have solved my problem by editing /etc/postgresql/*version_to_disable*/main/start.conf. I changed from 'auto' to 'manual', then ran "systemctl daemon-reload" and "sudo service postgresql restart".

Now, when I am run "psql --version" I see that version is 10. But where I am running "ps ax | grep postgres" command I see only postgresql 9.6 processes. Thanks!

Comment: great that you found a workaround, otherwise you can always refer to: [How to set a path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)